# Are there non-trivial MIP protocols with initially-independent verifiers?

Tags: interactive-proofs, nexp

My impression is that for standard constructions of [MIP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:M#mip) ("Multiple Independent Prover") protocols, the verifiers must have shared randomness. ​ What happens if the verifiers are

also independent until the interactions have all finished? ​ (i.e., Each independent

prover [interacts with a](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:I#ip) different independent verifier and then the transcripts

of the interactions get sent to the final verifier, which either accepts or rejects.)

More Formally: ​ What is known about the power of MIP protocols in which,

for each prover, the computation of what (if anything) the verifier sends

does not use anything about the partial transcripts for the other provers

and
the randomness strings used for the verifier's interactions

with different provers are independent of each other

?
By [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.6848v1.pdf), the *public coin minimal-interaction* version of that collapses to AM.

Comment: I don't understand the question. In the standard definition of MIP, there is only one verifier, and he does not share randomness with anyone.

Comment: Already a single prover with a single verifier and public coins can recognize all of PSPACE, so there is no way it can collapse all the way down to AM. Do you actually mean AM[poly(n)] (that is, PSPACE)? Or are the protocols implicitly restricted to a constant number of rounds?

Comment: I fixed the last line. ​ ​